# how to copy certain objects of an existing json array of objects to a new json array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

My JSON array of objects is:

```
[{
  "stateCd": "IL",
  "value": "Illinois",
  "selected": "false"
},
{
  "stateCd": "CA",
  "value": "California",
  "selected": "true"
},
{
  "stateCd": "NY",
  "value": "New york",
  "selected": "false"
}]
```

I want to create a new JSON array of objects which should only contain those objects from above array where `selected:false`.

I've tried `concat`:

```js
angular.forEach($scope.oldJsonArr, function (value, index) {
    if($scope.oldJsonArr[index].selected=="false"){
        $scope.newJsonArr.concat($scope.oldJsonArr[index]);
    }
});
```

But this is returning the `newJsonArr` as undefined.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you can use where in underscore.js if you are used underscore or use simple filter !

Comment: thanx...but i cannot use any other js files

Comment: Np. Use Filter from JS. check my answer with working demo

Comment: Added reference as well for your better understanding. checkout !

Comment: yeah...thats helpful..Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
$scope.oldJsonArr = [{"stateCd": "IL", "value": "Illinois", "selected": "false"}, {
        "stateCd": "CA",
        "value": "California",
        "selected": "true"
    }, {"stateCd": "NY", "value": "New york", "selected": "false"}];

    $scope.newJsonArr = [];

    angular.forEach($scope.oldJsonArr, function (value, index) {
        if ($scope.oldJsonArr[index].selected == "false") {
            $scope.newJsonArr.push($scope.oldJsonArr[index]);
        }
    });

    console.info($scope.newJsonArr);
```

1. You have to define variables, or they will remain `undefined`
2. You had to use `.push()` method

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.filter() method.

```
var falseFilter = function(value) {
    return value.selected == "false";
};

var newJsonArray = oldJsonArray.filter(falseFilter);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

Use `Filter` from `JavaScript` rather using library utility function.

```js
var people = [
  { firstname:"Micro",  hasSocialNetworkSite: false, lastname:"Soft", site:"http://microsoft.com" },
  { firstname:"Face",   hasSocialNetworkSite: true, lastname:"Book", site:"http://facebook.com" },
  { firstname:"Go",     hasSocialNetworkSite: true, lastname:"ogle", site:"http://google.com" },
  { firstname:"Twit",   hasSocialNetworkSite: true, lastname:"Ter", site:"http://twitter.com" },
  { firstname:"App",    hasSocialNetworkSite: false, lastname:"Le",   site:"http://apple.com" },
  { firstname:"Master", hasSocialNetworkSite: false, lastname:"Card", site:"http://mastercard.com" }
];

var filteredResult = people.filter(function(v) {
  return v.hasSocialNetworkSite == true; // Filter out the appropriate one
});

document.write("Social Networking Site<br>");

for (var i in filteredResult) {
  document.write(filteredResult[i].site + "<br>")
}
```

> Reference to know in detail:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679973(v=vs.94).aspx
>   http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp